# How to Link 3 List Boxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three list boxes and what I want is to when I click on the one of the numbers in the first list box I want the corresponding columns to also be highlighted, I have provided images of what I want it to be like.

[image: img]

Comment: Have you investigated the [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox?view=netframework-4.8#properties) of the `ListBox` object? There are some that might be useful to you.

Comment: You probably are looking for `DataGridView` or `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set the `SelectedIndex` of other listboxes:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ndx = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

    listBox2.SelectedIndex = ndx;
    listBox3.SelectedIndex = ndx;
}
```